# How to post body data using Fetch API?

Tags: javascript, json, postman, fetch-api

Below is the curl command that gives back the response successfully upon importing and running in postman.

```
    curl --request POST \
--data "grant_type=password" \
--data "username=test" \
--data "password=xyz1234" \
--data "scope=write" \
--data "client_id=test" \
--data "client_secret=test12" \
"https://example.com/access_token"
```

Below is how I am sending data using fetch api in my js code.

```
       const response = await fetch ('https://example.com/access_token', 

  {
    'credentials' : 'include',
     method: 'POST',
     headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
     body: JSON.stringify({ grant_type:'password',username:'test',password:'xyz1234',scope:'write',client_id:'test',client_secret:'test12'}),
})
```

However the equilavent curl which is generated after copying from chrome developer tools is below.

```
curl --request POST \
--data-raw '{"grant_type":"password","username":"test","password":"xyz1234","scope":"write","client_id":"test","client_secret":"test12"}'
"https://example.com/access_token"
```

I suspect that the body data is not constructed in the correct format. This may be leading to a 400 error code response. How should I send the data using fetch api equilavent to working curl command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the `curl` your data does seem to be URL encoded. So as it's not expecting JSON don't serialize it to a JSON string.

```js
const headers = new Headers({
  "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
});

const urlencoded = new URLSearchParams({
  "grant_type": "password",
  "username": "test",
  "password": "xyz1234",
  "scope": "write",
  "client_id": "test",
  "client_secret": "test12",
});

const opts = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: headers,
  body: urlencoded,
};

fetch("https://example.com/access_token", opts);
```

##### EDIT

As [@Kaiido](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3702797/kaiido) mentioned in the comments. It is not necessary to set the `Content-Type` header explicitly as the browser will do that automatically, but I have done it here to show you that it should not be set to `application/json` but to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: Passing the `URLSearchParams` as the body option is all that's needed, the browser will automatically set the Content-Type header accordingly.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've only added it because in OP's question it was explicitly set to `application/json`. I'll rephrase my answer to include that.